# The component of the sum of a number of vectors in the direction of another vector

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vectors

It appears to me to be self evident that in a three dimensional Euclidean space, the component of two or more vectors in the direction of the vector ${\bf w}$,  is just the summed component of each of the vectors in the direction of ${\bf w}$:
$$
(\bf u + \bf v + \bf \dots)_{w} = \bf u_{w} + \bf v_{w} + \dots
$$
Is further work needed here to prove this?

Comment: Projection on a vector (here $\mathbb{w}$) is a linear operator, so mentioning that is enough.

Comment: Hi category. You have not given any context here, so that makes it hard to answer. I guess you are interested in vector spaces such as the plane of high-school geometry, or real 3-space as seen in mechanics. You ask about proving. It depends what is given. Is an inner product space given? Or, are you trying to prove that real 3-space is an inner product space?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/185690 and also https://math.stackexchange.com/a/698483

Comment: Hi @311411, the vector space here is a three dimensional Euclidean space. I will update the question.

Comment: @311411 I'm not sure if I'm trying to prove the latter, that this space is an inner product space - I think this may be different, since I'm not mapping vectors to a scalar here.

Comment: I suppose that the projection matrix would be ${\mathbf{\hat{w}} \mathbf{\hat{w}}^{\mathsf{T}}}$ to get the projection onto  ${\mathbf{w}}$.

Comment: Then ${\mathbf{\hat{w}} \mathbf{\hat{w}}^{\mathsf{T}}(\mathbf{u} + \mathbf{v}) = \mathbf{\hat{w}} \mathbf{\hat{w}}^{\mathsf{T}}\mathbf{u} + \mathbf{\hat{w}} \mathbf{\hat{w}}^{\mathsf{T}}\mathbf{v}}$ as ${\mathbf{\hat{w}} \mathbf{\hat{w}}^{\mathsf{T}}}$ is a Linear Operator

Answer (score 1):

Building on the [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4169171/the-component-of-the-sum-of-a-number-of-vectors-in-the-direction-of-another-vect/4170347#comment8635319_4169171) that the 'Projection on a vector' is a linear operator, the component of the vector ${(\mathbf u + \mathbf v + \dots)}$ in the direction of ${\mathbf w}$ can be given by multiplying the said vector by the  projection matrix ${\mathbf {\mathbf {\hat{w}}} {\mathbf {\hat{w}^{\mathsf T}}}}$ :
$$
\mathbf {\mathbf {\hat{w}}} {\mathbf {\hat{w}^{\mathsf T}}} (\mathbf u + \mathbf v \dots)
$$
where the unit vector ${\mathbf {\hat{w}} = \frac {\mathbf{w}} {\|\mathbf{w}\|}}$.

Since the projection matrix represents a Linear Transformation, this can be written as:
$$
\mathbf {\mathbf {\hat{w}}} {\mathbf {\hat{w}^{\mathsf T}}} \mathbf u + \mathbf {\mathbf {\hat{w}}} {\mathbf {\hat{w}^{\mathsf T}}} \mathbf v + \dots
$$

Comment: I guess $\mathbf {\hat w}$ is the unit vector in the direction of $\mathbf w.$ That's the usual convention, but if you're actually writing up a proof I would define the vector explicitly and not rely on convention.

Comment: Updated to include the definition of the unit vector ${\mathbf {\hat{w}}}$.